# jQuery add another html tag to an existing tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I have this code from the browser console that is coming from Javascript of datatables plugin (All codes are shortened):

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="mytable_length">
<label>
"عرض "
<select name="mytable_length" aria-controls="mytable" class="form-select form-select-sm"></select>
 "نتائج"
</label>
</div>
```

and underneath of this code I have this code (All codes are shortened):

```
<div id="mytable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
<label>
"بحث: "
<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="mytable">
    </label>
    </div>
```

This is a picture taken from the browser console just to make things clear
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeLz9.png

Now I need to remove the parent tag `<div id="mytable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">`
and take/move the child tags with elements `label` and `input` and add them to/underneath `<div class="dataTables_length" id="mytable_length">` using jQuery. So the final code will be:

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="mytable_length">
<label>
"عرض "
<select name="mytable_length" aria-controls="mytable" class="form-select form-select-sm"></select>
 "نتائج"
</label>
<label>
"بحث: "
<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="mytable">
    </label>
</div>
```

using jQuery, what I did so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            $('.dataTables_filter').remove();
        },
    });
});
```

but this will only remove `<div id="mytable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">` with its child tags, and that's not what I need. How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just modify its id and class?

Comment: How? The datatables.js file is just messy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to remove the parent tag `<div id="mytable_filter" class="dataTables_filter">` and take/move the child tags with elements label and input and add them to/underneath `<div class="dataTables_length" id="mytable_length">`

Appending nodes to a given container is a basic operation in jQuery. Select the nodes, use `.appendTo()`, done.

```
$(function () {
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            $('.dataTables_filter').children().appendTo('#mytable_length');
            $('.dataTables_filter').remove();
        },
    });
});
```

A DOM node can only have one parent. If you append it to a different parent, it will effectively be removed from its current parent.

Comment: Oh my god! Perfect! It worked exactly what I want! Now I just need to add some styles to it. Thanks! 100% best answer!

Comment: Now I need to add an id for the first label like so `<label id = "test1"` and for the second label test 2 also using jQuery. I did that `$('label').attr('id', 'test1');` but it gives both label same id... I need each label to have different id. How to specify which label to add its id?

Comment: @DBblack Meditate over https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it and I didn't understand... I am not that good at jQuery... Can you please just post the code for my example above?

Comment: @DBblack No. Scroll to "Computed attribute values" and think some more. You'll figure it out.

Comment: @DBblack Computing values like this works for many other jQuery functions, not only `.attr()`. A neat feature to keep in mind.